# Inserir informações no banco com AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Estou precisando inserir uma informação no banco de dados, porem preciso que a página não atualize.

o problema é que não conheço nada de AJAX e mesmo buscando os códigos na net, não consegui resolver

Como estou fazendo:

```
function setEpisodeComplete(episodeID, midiaType){
var url = "../control/ayzac_control_setComplete.php?id=" + episodeID + "&tp=" + midiaType;
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    error: function(){
        alert('Erro: Inserir Registo!!');
    },
    success: function(result)
    { 
        if($.trim(result) == '1')
        {
            alert("O seu registo foi inserido com sucesso!");
        }
        else{
            alert("Ocorreu um erro ao inserir o seu registo!");
        }

    }
});}
```

Ele sempre cai na mensagem "Ocorreu um erro ao inserir o seu registo!"

Se faltou alguma informação para vocês me ajudarem, me avisem por favor. Obrigado!

@edit

Vou postar os código mais completos pra ficar mais fácil entender, desconfio que meu erro possa não estar necessariamente no js

Como ficou a função JS:
    function setEpisodeComplete(episodeID, midiaType) {

```
var url = "../control/ayzac_control_setComplete.php";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    cache:false,
    data: {"id": episodeID, "tp": midiaType},

    error: function () {
        alert('Erro: Inserir Registo!!');
    }
    ,
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        if ($.trim(result) == '1')
        {
            alert("O seu registo foi inserido com sucesso!");
        } else {
            alert("Ocorreu um erro ao inserir o seu registo!");
        }
    }
}
);}
```

O arquivo que o JS chama ayzac_control_setComplete.pho:

```
require ('../models/ayzac_class_midia.php');
$objUser = new userMidia();
session_start();
$userId =   $_SESSION['idSession'];
$midiaId = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'id');
$midiaType = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'tp');
$midiaId = $objUser->removeChar($midiaId);
$midiaType = $objUser->removeChar($midiaType);
var_dump($midiaType);
$objUser->setComplete($midiaId,$userId,$midiaType);
```

E por fim o código em php:

```
function setComplete($midiaId, $userID, $midiaType) {
    $connect = new ControllerConnect ();
    $objCon = $connect->controllerConnect();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ayzac_midia_status WHERE ayzac_user_id = '" . $userID . "' AND ayzac_midia_id = '" . $midiaId . "'";
    $query = $objCon->executeSQLQuery($sql);
    if ($midiaType == 1) {
        if ($objCon->getSqlNumRows($query) >= 1) {
            $sql = "UPDATE ayzac_midia_status SET ayzac_midia_status = '2' WHERE ayzac_user_id = '" . $userID . "' AND ayzac_midia_id = '" . $midiaId . "'";
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO ayzac_midia_status (ayzac_user_id,ayzac_midia_id,ayzac_midia_status) VALUES ('" . $userID . "','" . $midiaId . "','2')";
        }
    } else if ($midiaType == 2) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ayzac_season WHERE ayzac_midia_id ='" . $midiaId . "'";
        $season = $objCon->executeSQLFetchAssoc($sql);
        $i = 0;
        while (isset($season [$i] ['ayzac_season_id'])) {
            $sql2 = "SELECT ayzac_episode_id FROM ayzac_episode WHERE ayzac_season_id = '" . $season [$i] ['ayzac_season_id'] . "'";
            $episodes = $objCon->executeSQLFetchArray2($sql2);
            $j = 0;
            while (isset($episodes [$j] ['ayzac_episode_id'])) {
                $this->setEpisodeComplete($userID, $episodes [$j] ['ayzac_episode_id']);
                $j ++;
            }
            $i ++;
        }

        if ($objCon->getSqlNumRows($query) >= 1) {
            $sql = "UPDATE ayzac_midia_status SET ayzac_midia_status = '2' WHERE ayzac_user_id = '" . $userID . "' AND ayzac_midia_id = '" . $midiaId . "'";
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO ayzac_midia_status (ayzac_user_id,ayzac_midia_id,ayzac_midia_status) VALUES ('" . $userID . "','" . $midiaId . "','2')";
        }
    } else if ($midiaType == 3) {
        if ($objCon->getSqlNumRows($query) >= 1) {
            $sql = "UPDATE ayzac_midia_status SET ayzac_midia_status = '2' WHERE ayzac_user_id = '" . $userID . "' AND ayzac_midia_id = '" . $midiaId . "'";
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO ayzac_midia_status (ayzac_user_id,ayzac_midia_id,ayzac_midia_status) VALUES ('" . $userID . "','" . $midiaId . "','2')";
        }
    }
    $objCon->executeSQLQuery($sql);
    echo 1;
}
```

Fiz um var_dump no comando sql pra ver como estava, e descobri que veio assim:

```
SELECT * FROM ayzac_season WHERE ayzac_midia_id =&#39;12&#39;
```

Provavelmente é por isso que não esta dando certo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente a requisição ao seu script foi feita com sucesso, mas ele está retornando um resultado diferente de `1`. Altere a url e passe os dados pelo atributo `data` e use o método `POST` para inserir dados.

Você tem que acompanhar o que seu script em PHP exibe, a melhor forma de fazer isso é adicionar o parâmetro `dataType: "html"` na função $.ajax e exibir no console o resultado da função `success`.

Tente isso:

```
function setEpisodeComplete(episodeID, midiaType){
    var url = "../control/ayzac_control_setComplete.php";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {"id": episodeID, "tp"= midiaType}
        error: function(){
            alert('Erro: Inserir Registo!!');
        },
        success: function(result) { 
            console.log(result);
            if($.trim(result) == '1')
            {
                alert("O seu registo foi inserido com sucesso!");
            } else {
                alert("Ocorreu um erro ao inserir o seu registo!");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Depois é só ver o resultado na aba console do chrome `CTRL+F12`. Acredito que esteja com algum erro no PHP, pode um erro de sintaxe ou com o próprio SQL que está executando.

E não esqueça de alterar o script PHP para receber os dados com POST usando a variável global $_POST ou a função [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php), que recomendo!